# Howl is not defined Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, howler.js

I installed howler using

```
npm install -g  howler --save
```

Added script

```
require('howler');
```

Even in index.html file I added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.4/howler.js"></script>
```

It seems to work but every time my app reloads (I use npm run serve to run app) I get error Howl is not defined.Then I install howler once again using npm it works, but again after reloading stops working.
So basically I need to reinstall howler again and again.

Comment: Can you share the whole file? I would like to see how you are using the howler import in the actual file. Also, install howler locally to the project rather than globally. That might help your modules find it more reliably.

Comment: I create Howl instance using mounted hook. Installing locally did not help.

Comment: `npm install -g  howler --save` makes no sense. Use `npm i howler` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Installation

The `-g` flag tells NPM to install the package *globally*. The `--save` flag tells NPM to install it *locally* in your project (and to save it in `package.json` under `dependencies`). Those two flags are mutually exclusive, but `-g` will override `--save`. The solution there is to remove the `-g` flag, while keeping `--save`.

And if you're `require`ing it in your project, don't also import from CDN in `index.html` (i.e., remove the `<script>`).

#### Usage

To use `Howl` in your code, make sure to assign the return value from `require('howler')`:

```js
const { Howl } = require('howler');

const sound = new Howl({
  src: ['sound.mp3']
});

sound.play();
```